# Why does my API Gateway HTTP proxy return 404?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up API gateway to proxy all requests to a different domain. I set it up using the terraform code below, and everything seems to be in place. But when I try to call it, all I get is `{"message":"Not Found"}` from API Gateway. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```hcl
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.2.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.1.6"
}

provider "aws" {
  region              = "eu-west-1"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "example" {
  name          = "example"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "example" {
  api_id           = aws_apigatewayv2_api.example.id
  integration_type = "HTTP_PROXY"

  integration_method = "ANY"
  integration_uri    = "https://example.com"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "example" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.example.id
  route_key = "$default"

  target   = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.example.id}"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "example" {
  api_id   = aws_apigatewayv2_api.example.id
  name     = "example"
}
```

I've also tried adding access logging to the stage. Nothing shows up in the logs, which might be a hint as to what is going on.

PS. I know there are other ways of doing this, such as CloudFront. Unfortunately it *has* to be API Gateway in this particular case.

Comment: How are you calling it exactly? Do you have any example in curl or postman?

Comment: I navigate to the url (https://7mbw1gmu16.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/example) in the browser. But it's the same story in curl. [curl -v output](https://pastebin.com/3JpqtAu0)

Comment: Can you make it work with API created using AWS Console? This is just to confirm that your issue is TF specific, and has nothing to do with the way how you call its endpoint or the url you are redirecting to.

Comment: Interesting! I created the same API in the console, and the stage I created had the same error. But the auto-created $default stage did work.

Comment: Turns out I didn't have a deployment. `auto_deploy = true` and I'm up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was missing a deployment. Easiest way to get up and running:

```hcl
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "example" {
  api_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_api.example.id
  name        = "example"
  auto_deploy = true
}
```